# Most appropriate api for accessing Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-api-python-client

I want to read a Google Spreadsheet from a python App Engine application. I have used the Google APIs Client Library for Python for a few things. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation

I see how I could use that with the Drive API. However, for spreadsheets, it seems that the old gdata Google Spreadsheets API using OAUTH 2.0 has the right api / features. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20

So I am a little confused. Currently (May 2014), what is the correct and best api to use for this case of reading spreadsheets?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the Drive API will help you create, delete or again update metadata for a Google Spreadsheet (or other kinds of files).

However when it comes to interacting with a Google Spreadsheet content, the GData Google Spreadsheets API is, unfortunately, currently the only way to do that (Apps Script APIs aside).
As you mentioned, you can use OAuth 2.0 as well with GData.

I guess a lot of us were hoping for a brand new API with the new Google Sheets but instead the old one "was made compatible" with the new versions of Sheets.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can get OAuth 2.0 going with GData and post results here for the sake of completeness.